# Need help querying through 3 classes

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 classes that are defined like this:

```
class Customer
{

    public string Name;
    public string City;
    public Order[] Orders;
}

class Order
{

    public int Quantity;
    public Product Product;
}

class Product
{

    public string ProdName;
    public decimal Price;
}
```

And I want to use LINQ in C# to print out the names that bought a specific product which in this case is 'ProdName'. I can't find a solution in order to go through all these 3 classes that could give me the name based on the product name.

I have tried something like this but it seems it doesn;t work:

```
var query = from c in customers where c.Order[0].Product.ProdName.Contains("Milk")
select c.Name;

foreach(var item in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This is how I set up the values for each class:

```
 static public List<Customer> GetCustomerList()
 {

    var customerList = new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer {Name = "Johny", City = "London", Orders = new Order[3] },
        new Customer {Name = "Morgan", City = "Copenhagen", Orders = new Order[4]},
        new Customer {Name = "Rasmus", City = "Amsterdam", Orders = new Order[1] }
    };

    return customerList;
}

static public List<Order> GetOrderList()
{

    var orderList = new List<Order>
    {
        new Order { Quantity = 10, Product = new Product()},
        new Order { Quantity = 5, Product = new Product()},
        new Order { Quantity = 2, Product = new Product()}
    };

    return orderList;
}

static public List<Product> GetProductList()
{

    var productList = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product { Name = "Cookie, bread", Price = 50 },
        new Product { Name = "Cookie, Bread, Milk", Price = 85},
        new Product { Name = "bags", Price = 38}
    };

    return productList;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList();
    List<Order> orders = GetOrderList();
    List<Product> products = GetProductList();
}
```

How can I linq all 3 classes together in order to get right result? any hints, please?

Comment: Your query will never return what you want today because your test data is not properly structured. You have Customers with empty Order arrays, Orders without products, and products with no names or prices.

Comment: If I query each class I get want I want but if I want to get a name based on what is in the Product class I get nothing. Every variable is set up with a value.

Comment: You are not mapping products to orders:
`new Order { Quantity = 10, Product = new Product()},` - each order has a new instance of product, without name and price. It can't work.

Comment: Now I know what you are saying...I thought that setting them up like I did should do the trick...but it seems that it doesn't. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Also consider changing your classes to use properties instead of public fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build real, related, test data. Some usable fake data setup might look like:

```
// Create a single instance of each Product that could be used
var egg = new Product { Name = "Eggs", Price = 2.0 };
var bread = new Product { Name = "Bread", Price = 3.0 };
var fooBars = new Product { Name = "FooBars", Price = 2.5 };

var customerList = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { Name = "Johny", City = "London", Orders = new List<Order> 
    {
        new Order { Quantity = 3, Product = bread },
        new Order { Quantity = 1, Product = egg },
        new Order { Quantity = 2, Product = fooBars }
    }},
    new Customer { Name = "Morgan", City = "Copenhagen", Orders = new List<Order>
    {
        new Order { Quantity = 30, Product = bread }
    }},
    new Customer { Name = "Rasmus", City = "Amsterdam", Orders = new List<Order>
    {
        new Order { Quantity = 12, Product = fooBars }
    }}
};
```

Please note that I used `List<Order>` instead of `Order[]`, but you could switch it back. I also opted for a `Name` property in `Product` as you showed in your example code, but which doesn't match your class definition.

Now you can query. Let's see who bought bread:

```
var whoBoughtBread = customerList
    .Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.Product == bread))
    .Select(c => c.Name);
```

Or

```
var whoBoughtBread2 = customerList
    .Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.Product.Name == "Bread"))
    .Select(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: Since you've changed the type and names of some of the fields it might be helpful to the OP to show them how you would define those classes to match this code.

Comment: I will correct the code and give it a try then I will comeback with an answer. Thank you for the example!

Comment: I think the only difference is `Product.Name` instead of `Product.ProdName`, right?

Comment: You're also using a `List<Order>` instead of `Order[]`.

Comment: I do know what I have to do now so there is no need to have the same names in order to understand the process.

Comment: @juharr: I added a little explanation after the code example for any further clarification it might add.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, I get the right result after following your example. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With the data structure you have one query would be:

```
customerList.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.Product.ProdName == prodName));
```

but as mentioned in the comments you have potentials for both a `null` collection and `null` values *within* the collection.  I would highly recommend making sure you have non-null collections with non-null elements to avoid having to inject null-checking into your query.  Otherwise you'll have to do sometihng like:

```
customerList.Where(c => c.Orders != null &&
                        c.Orders.Any(o => o != null &&
                                          o.Product != null &&
                                          o.Product.ProdName == prodName));
```

With C# 6's null-propagation operator (`?.`) you can shorten it a *little*:

```
customerList.Where(c => c.Orders != null &&
                        c.Orders.Any(o => o?.Product != null &&
                                          o.Product.ProdName == prodName));
```

Comment: Actually the `Orders` are not `null`, just empty.